# how to use python regex functions in dbt-jinja?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

[this PR](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt/pull/2851) adds all the `re` module functions to dbt-jinja, but how to use it? I tried the below two, but to no avail.

```sql
{% set matcher = re.match('Doug', 'Timestamps Doug') %}
're' is undefined. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".
```

```sql
{% set matcher = match('Doug', 'Timestamps Doug') %}
> 'match' is undefined. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as was pointed out in a comment in the PR, there is [a doc page](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/modules#re) that details that to use the `re` module,  you prefix it's usage with `modules.`

```py
{% set matcher = modules.re.match('Doug', 'Timestamps Doug') %}
```